# OGR merge shapefiles of different geom type into a single GeoJSON feature collection

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr, topojson

I'd like to merge shapefiles of different geometry types into a single geojson feature collection, but OGR says it doesn't support update of GeoJSON files:

```
$ ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs crs:84 -lco GEOMETRY_AS_COLLECTION merge.geojson points.shp
$ ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs crs:84 -update -append merge.geojson -lco GEOMETRY_AS_COLLECTION lines.shp -nln merged
ERROR 4: GeoJSON Driver doesn't support update.
FAILURE:
Unable to open existing output datasource `merge.geojson'.
```

This seems like a common use case to me. Am I missing something obvious in the ogr2ogr manual? I can put together something in python (and finally use fiona) but I'm rather surprised I don't see anything existing when searching here or github... which makes me thing I'm messing something up.

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> Fortunately, OGR objects model does allow to have geometries of
>   different types in single layer - a heterogeneous layer.

Source: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_geojson.html

For instance, if we have three shapefiles of different geometry types (`points.shp`, `lines.shp` and `polygons.shp`) we can define the union layer using the [OGR VRT driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_vrt.html) specifying its geometry type as `wkbGeometryCollection`. So we can write the following VRT file, named i.e. `merge.vrt`:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTUnionLayer name="union">
        <OGRVRTLayer name="points">
            <SrcDataSource>points.shp</SrcDataSource>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
        <OGRVRTLayer name="lines">
            <SrcDataSource>lines.shp</SrcDataSource>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
        <OGRVRTLayer name="polygons">
            <SrcDataSource>polygons.shp</SrcDataSource>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
        <GeometryType>wkbGeometryCollection</GeometryType>
    </OGRVRTUnionLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Then, we can easily convert `merge.vrt` into `merge.geojson`, preserving all the attributes of the source layers, simply executing:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON merge.geojson merge.vrt
```

Finally, you can check if the conversion is done successfully:

```
ogrinfo merge.geojson OGRGeoJSON
```

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question. I didn't know about the VRT driver. I stopped using topojson and have been  using merge-geojsons https://gist.github.com/migurski/3759608 as recommended by another user, whos comment seems to be gone.

Answer (score 0):

A modification of fiona's dumpgj to handle multiple inputs seemed to be the way to go.

http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html#dumpgj

I started - and was learning things - but then remembered that topojson accepts multiple inputs and it seems to work.

https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference