# Merging shapefiles with different geometries (point and polygon) to get single layer with multiple geometries?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geojson, file-formats

I want to merge two shape files in which one is of point geometry type and other is polygon type in order to get a single layer containing both points and polygon in a single map.

Answer (score 12):

[**Shapefile**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) format doesn't allow multiple geometry types, so you should use another format, like [**GeoJSON**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON). See also [OGR merge shapefiles of different geom type into a single GeoJSON feature collection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74175/ogr-merge-shapefiles-of-different-geom-type-into-a-single-geojson-feature-collec?rq=1), [How to Merge/Join GeoJSON and JSON?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41403/how-to-merge-join-geojson-and-json) and https://gist.github.com/migurski/3759608

Answer (score 5):

But you can group two layers together if you are trying to save mouse clicks on switching them on and off.

Answer (score 3):

You can buffer the point and save it. Then in QGIS go to Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Merge shapefiles to one. If you want geojson, then you can now convert the merged shapefiles to geojson.