# Writing shapefile of multiple geometry using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely, pyshp

How to make a shapefile containing points, polygon, and line using python shapely or pyshp?

Comment: It is impossible. Read the spec https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf.

Answer (score 4):

a shapefile can only contain one geometry-type.  For each of them, you have to create another shapefile.

More info: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/74629/7849